# How to typeset two verse environments side by side

Tags: positioning, verse

I'm doing a poem analysis of some English poem translated to Swedish. I want include the poem in both the languages, like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verse}

\begin{document}

\settowidth{\versewidth}{Mitt hjärta, stilla dina slag,}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
  Mitt hjärta, stilla dina slag, \\
  sen andra hjärtan slutits till! \\
  Men - kan jag ej bli älskad, jag \\
  \vin dock älska vill.
\end{verse}

\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
  'T is time this heart should be unmoved, \\
  \vin Since others it hath ceased to move: \\
  Yet, though I cannot be beloved, \\
  \vin \vin Still let me love!
\end{verse}

From this part we can see that bla bla bla \dots

\end{document}
```

This code results in:

[image]

But I'd also like to typeset these two versions side by side, in two separate columns. How may I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of options to do what you want. One possibility would be to use `minipage`s; the width for each minipage will be given by the corresponding `\versewidth` (`+1pt`, since `\versewidth` alone doesn't work).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verse}

\begin{document}

\settowidth{\versewidth}{Men - kan jag ej bli älskad, jag}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\versewidth+1pt\relax}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
  Mitt hjärta, stilla dina slag, \\
  sen andra hjärtan slutits till! \\
  Men - kan jag ej bli älskad, jag \\
  \vin dock älska vill.
\end{verse}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\settowidth{\versewidth}{'T is time this heart should be unmoved,}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\versewidth+1pt\relax}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
  'T is time this heart should be unmoved, \\
  \vin Since others it hath ceased to move: \\
  Yet, though I cannot be beloved, \\
  \vin\vin Still let me love!
\end{verse}
\end{minipage}\bigskip

From this part we can see that bla bla bla \dots

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does the `t` option to the minipage environment do?

Comment: @Eric: it aligns both `minipage`s vertically to their tops.

Comment: Would the solution still work without the `\noindent`? Because it looks better without it.

Comment: @Eric: without the `\noindent` command, an overfull box will appear, since a new paragraph is starting and `\parindent` will be used.

Comment: You're misusing the optional argument to `verse`; moreover there's no need to guess the size of the minipages.

Comment: @egreg. thanks. I was just editing my answer. It's kind of wierd that `\versewidth` alone won't work for the `minipage`s width...

Comment: @Eric: I've updated my answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Actually 1sp seems to be sufficient: weird.

Answer (score 3):

```
\begin{center}
\settowidth{\versewidth}{Men - kan jag ej bli älskad, jag}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\versewidth+1sp\relax}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
  Mitt hjärta, stilla dina slag, \\
  sen andra hjärtan slutits till! \\
  Men - kan jag ej bli älskad, jag \\
  \vin dock älska vill.
\end{verse}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\settowidth{\versewidth}{'T is time this heart should be unmoved,}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\versewidth+1sp\relax}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
  'T is time this heart should be unmoved, \\
  \vin Since others it hath ceased to move: \\
  Yet, though I cannot be beloved, \\
  \vin \vin Still let me love!
\end{verse}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
```

Strangely enough, `\begin{minipage}[t]{\versewidth}` is not sufficient.

It's best to set `\versewidth` to the maximum verse length.

Comment: would adding a space at the end of the argument to `\settowidth` make it possible to use just the `\versewidth`?  all the lines of the verse in the input do end with spaces, which i don't think are automatically ignored at the ends of lines.  (or, alternatively, just putting `\\` tight up against the last word in each line.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Adding a space will do, but the weird thing is that 1sp suffices! Probably a rounding problem similar to `\hbox to 2in{\hskip1in \hskip1in}`

Comment: maybe a rounding problem indeed; do you know if the `\hbox ...` example has been documented as a known bug?  if not (and i don't have time now to research it), then if you can put together a cogent and compact report, i'll be glad to put it in the queue for dek.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I don't think it qualifies as a bug: it's just an effect of truncation in binary arithmetic; I believe to have seen it documented by David Kastrup. Perhaps in TUGboat, but I don't remember.