# Typesetting long poetry side by side across multiple pages

Tags: positioning, page-breaking

I've been trying to typeset a long poem (The Lady of Shalott) and putting the translated text besides it, as it is shown in this question: [How to typeset two verse environments side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29932/4778)

However, the poem in question is quite long and using the `minipage` envinronment is not feasible since it doesn't let the poem span across multiple pages.

The fact is that, for example, I need to keep the line-to-line correspondence (if a verse bar goes to a new line because it's too long, the other one should reflect that change).

Comment: There are, I'm sure, better solutions when only two "columns" are needed.  Nonetheless, this approach developed for 6 columns may (or may not) have something to offer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130907/how-do-i-create-6-parallel-texts-aligned-by-paragraph-with-3-texts-on-each-page/131394#131394

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks for the link! However, that solution seems a bit too complicated for what I want to do. I was hoping for something simpler. :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the [parallel](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/parallel/parallel.pdf) package.

To achieve the result you want, you can use:

```
\begin{Parallel}
\ParallelLText{<left-text>}
\ParallelRText{} % empty right column
\ParallelPar
\ParallelLText{} % empty left column
\ParallelRText{<right-text>}
\end{Parallel}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{parallel}

\begin{document}

\begin{Parallel}[c]{0.5\textwidth}{0.5\textwidth}
\ParallelLText{%
{\noindent \bfseries PASADO EN CLARO}\
\medskip
\noindent
Oídos con el alma\\
pasos mentales mas que sombras,\\
sombras del pensamiento más que pasos,\\
por el camino de ecos\\
que la memoria inventa y borra:\\
sin caminar caminan\\
sobre este ahora, puente\\
tendido entre una letra y otra.\\
Como llovizna sobre brasas\\
dentro de mí los pasos pasan\\
hacia lugares que se vuelven aire.\\
}

\ParallelRText{%
{\noindent \bfseries A DRAFT OF SHADOWS}\
\medskip
\noindent
Heard by the soul, footsteps\\
in the mind more than shadows,\\
shadows of thought more than footsteps\\
through the path of echoes\\
that memory invents and erases:\\
without walking they walk\\
over this present, bridge\\
slung from one letter to the next.\\
Like drizzle on embers,\\
footsteps within me step\\
toward places that turn to air.\\
}
\renewcommand{\ParallelAtEnd}{\hfill\textit{Octavio Paz}
}

\end{Parallel}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result:]